# how can i change value of transform with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a block

```
<div class="some"></some>
```

And I want to change it with jQuery css callback function

just like

```
$(".some").css('height', function(i, value){
    return parseFloat(value) * 1.2;
});
```

but if i will call

```
$(".some").css("transorm") it returns "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -0.0212)"
```

and i need only transformY, the last value,
How can i take it?

Comment: Refer http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var res =  $(".some").css("transorm");  // returns "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -0.0212)

   var values = res.split('(')[1];
   values = values.split(')')[0];
   values = values.split(',');
   var your_value = values[5]; //has '-0.0212'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/8bAtN/

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $(".some").css("transform", function(i){
            return 'translateY('+ i + 50 +'px)';
        });
});
```